# How can I added some sub html project to a django project

Tags: python, html, django

Now I have a django project and some small html project (in fact, some html5 games). How can I added the html site to the django project?

For the each html project has ref a lot of css, img and javascript in its own folder, and different html site are in different folder.

Hence, I can not now just do like this:

```
t = get_template('htmlprojectfolder/index.html')

html = t.render(Context())

return HttpResponse(html)
```

I think my problem is:

"how can I jump to a html index page with its static files correct linked?" (Clealy, I can not read just the index page as a template file.)

Thank you for help!

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: E, sorry for my poor english. I want added some html project to a django project. But those all those html project has ref a lot of css, img and javascript in its own folder. So differnt html project have static files in different folder.  I can not read their index page as a template because those static files. Hence I do not know how can I jump to those html project with those static files correct linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to add static, non-Django files that shall be accessible via a Django project would be to add the files to the `STATICFILES_DIR`. You can read more about static files [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) in the Django documentation.

Another, and possibly better, way to handle this would be to let the webserver serve the static files separately from Django.

Comment: Thank u, I will have a try.